# Добавление оплаты в инлайн клавиатуру на aioogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

У меня есть код бота с инлайн клавиатурами и есть второй код с со реализацией тестовой оплаты.
Во втором коде оплата вызывается по определённым командам(action, mmo, rgp), нужно сделать так чтобы предложение оплатить и само окно оплаты выходило после выбора определённого жанра на инлайн клавиатуре

вот инлайн клавитаура:

[image: инлайн клавиатура]

вот что должно выводиться после выбора жанра:
[image: оплата]

вот первый код(с выбором жанров)

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher, FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils import executor
from config import TOKEN

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)



class Games(StatesGroup):
    game = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton('Action', callback_data='Action'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('MMO', callback_data='MMO'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('RPG', callback_data='RPG')
    )
    await message.answer('Здравствуйте!\nВы находитесь в магазине игр\nВыберите жанр игры:', reply_markup=keyboard)
    await Games.game.set()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

вот второй код(с оплатой)

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from config import BOT_TOKEN
# from filters import AdminFilter
from dataclasses import dataclass
bot = Bot(token="TOKEN", parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


@dp.message_handler(Command('action'))
async def show_invoices(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.from_user.id,
                           **ACTION.generate_invoices(), payload='12345')


@dp.message_handler(Command('mmo'))
async def show_invoices(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.from_user.id,
                           **MMO.generate_invoices(), payload='12345')


@dp.message_handler(Command('rgp'))
async def show_invoices(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.from_user.id,
                           **RGP.generate_invoices(), payload='12345')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Здравствуйте!\nВы находитесь в онлайн магазине компютерных игр\nПожалуйста, воспользуйтесь кнопкой menu')



@dataclass
class Item:
    title: str
    description: str
    start_parameter: str
    currency: str
    prices: list[types.LabeledPrice]
    provider_data: dict = None
    photo_url: str = None
    photo_size: int = None
    photo_width: int = None
    photo_height: int = None
    need_name: bool = False
    need_phone_number: bool = False
    need_email: bool = False
    need_shipping_address: bool = False
    send_phone_number_to_provider: bool = False
    send_email_to_provider: bool = False
    is_flexible: bool = False
    provider_token: str = "1744374395:TEST:ea0c4341c636a3a91eef"

    def generate_invoices(self):
        return self.__dict__


ACTION = Item(
    title='ACTION',
    description="Жанр компьютерных игр, в котором делается упор на эксплуатацию физических возможностей игрока.\nЖанр представлен во множестве разновидностей от файтингов, шутеров и до платформеров",
    currency='RUB',
    prices=[types.LabeledPrice(label="игры жанра Action:", amount= 300000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Доставка', amount=15000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Скидка', amount=-20000)],
    start_parameter='create_invoice_lenovo_3',
    photo_url="https://portagame.ru/katalog/game/xbox-game/xboxone-just-cause-4_4.jpg",
    photo_size=350500,
    need_shipping_address=True,
    is_flexible=True
)

MMO = Item(
    title='MMO',
    description="Жанр компьютерных игр, основанный на элементах игрового процесса традиционных настольных ролевых игр.",
    currency='RUB',
    prices=[types.LabeledPrice(label="игры жанра MMO:", amount= 190000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Доставка', amount=15000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Скидка', amount=-20000)],
    start_parameter='create_invoice_lenovo_3',
    photo_url="https://onyxgame.com/img/game/royal-quest/screenshots/royal-quest-image-screenshot-7.jpg",
    photo_size=535500,
    need_shipping_address=True,
    is_flexible=True
)


RGP = Item(
    title='RGP',
    description="Жанр компьютерных игр, основанный на элементах игрового процесса традиционных настольных ролевых игр.",
    currency='RUB',
    prices=[types.LabeledPrice(label="игры жанра RGP:", amount=230000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Доставка', amount=15000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Скидка', amount=-21000)],
    start_parameter='create_invoice_lenovo_3',
    photo_url="https://kingame.ru/wp-content/uploads/5/1/f/51f9c4452ad5c60225306c8d0cfafa67.jpeg",
    photo_size=2535500,
    need_shipping_address=True,
    is_flexible=True
)


POST_REGULAR_SHIPPING = types.ShippingOption(
    id='post_reg',
    title='Почтой',
    prices=[
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Обычная коробка', 0
        ),
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Почтой', 500_00
        ),
    ]
)


POST_FAST_SHIPPING = types.ShippingOption(
    id='post_fast',
    title='Почтой, ускоренная',
    prices=[
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Прочная упаковка', 200_00
        ),
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Срочной почтой', 1000_00
        ),
    ]
)


PICKUP_SHIPPING = types.ShippingOption(
    id='pickup',
    title='Самовывоз',
    prices=[
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Самовывоз из магазина', -100_00
        ),
    ]
)


@dp.shipping_query_handler()
async def choose_shipping(query: types.ShippingQuery):
    if query.shipping_address.country_code == 'RU':
        await bot.answer_shipping_query(shipping_query_id=query.id,
                                        shipping_options=[
                                            POST_REGULAR_SHIPPING,
                                            POST_FAST_SHIPPING,
                                            PICKUP_SHIPPING
                                        ],
                                        ok=True)
    elif query.shipping_address.country_code:
        await bot.answer_shipping_query(shipping_query_id=query.id,
                                        ok=False,
                                        error_message='Мы патриоты и работаем только по России\nВ выбранную вами страну товар не доставляем')



@dp.pre_checkout_query_handler()
async def process_pre_checkout_query(query: types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query_id=query.id, ok=True)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=query.from_user.id, text='Спасибо за покупку')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, их соединить

Comment: @ZxNuClear можете посмотреть, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно выводить инлайн клавиатуру при команде `/start`, а далее при выборе жанра перекидывать на окно оплаты второго кода. В таком случае вам и машина состояний не нужна, достаточно заменить хэндлеры, чтобы они ловили не команды, а колбэки от кнопок:

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from dataclasses import dataclass
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN", parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


@dataclass
class Item:
    title: str
    description: str
    start_parameter: str
    currency: str
    prices: list[types.LabeledPrice]
    provider_data: dict = None
    photo_url: str = None
    photo_size: int = None
    photo_width: int = None
    photo_height: int = None
    need_name: bool = False
    need_phone_number: bool = False
    need_email: bool = False
    need_shipping_address: bool = False
    send_phone_number_to_provider: bool = False
    send_email_to_provider: bool = False
    is_flexible: bool = False
    provider_token: str = "PAYMENT TOKEN" # Тут не забудьте указать токен платежной системы, который выдает BotFather

    def generate_invoices(self):
        return self.__dict__


ACTION = Item(
    title='ACTION',
    description="Жанр компьютерных игр, в котором делается упор на эксплуатацию физических возможностей игрока.\nЖанр представлен во множестве разновидностей от файтингов, шутеров и до платформеров",
    currency='RUB',
    prices=[types.LabeledPrice(label="игры жанра Action:", amount=300000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Доставка', amount=15000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Скидка', amount=-20000)],
    start_parameter='create_invoice_lenovo_3',
    photo_url="https://portagame.ru/katalog/game/xbox-game/xboxone-just-cause-4_4.jpg",
    photo_size=350500,
    need_shipping_address=True,
    is_flexible=True
)

MMO = Item(
    title='MMO',
    description="Жанр компьютерных игр, основанный на элементах игрового процесса традиционных настольных ролевых игр.",
    currency='RUB',
    prices=[types.LabeledPrice(label="игры жанра MMO:", amount=190000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Доставка', amount=15000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Скидка', amount=-20000)],
    start_parameter='create_invoice_lenovo_3',
    photo_url="https://onyxgame.com/img/game/royal-quest/screenshots/royal-quest-image-screenshot-7.jpg",
    photo_size=535500,
    need_shipping_address=True,
    is_flexible=True
)

RGP = Item(
    title='RGP',
    description="Жанр компьютерных игр, основанный на элементах игрового процесса традиционных настольных ролевых игр.",
    currency='RUB',
    prices=[types.LabeledPrice(label="игры жанра RGP:", amount=230000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Доставка', amount=15000),
            types.LabeledPrice(label='Скидка', amount=-21000)],
    start_parameter='create_invoice_lenovo_3',
    photo_url="https://kingame.ru/wp-content/uploads/5/1/f/51f9c4452ad5c60225306c8d0cfafa67.jpeg",
    photo_size=2535500,
    need_shipping_address=True,
    is_flexible=True
)

POST_REGULAR_SHIPPING = types.ShippingOption(
    id='post_reg',
    title='Почтой',
    prices=[
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Обычная коробка', 0
        ),
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Почтой', 500_00
        ),
    ]
)

POST_FAST_SHIPPING = types.ShippingOption(
    id='post_fast',
    title='Почтой, ускоренная',
    prices=[
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Прочная упаковка', 200_00
        ),
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Срочной почтой', 1000_00
        ),
    ]
)

PICKUP_SHIPPING = types.ShippingOption(
    id='pickup',
    title='Самовывоз',
    prices=[
        types.LabeledPrice(
            'Самовывоз из магазина', -100_00
        ),
    ]
)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton('Action', callback_data='Action'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('MMO', callback_data='MMO'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('RPG', callback_data='RPG')
    )
    await message.answer('Здравствуйте!\nВы находитесь в магазине игр\nВыберите жанр игры:', reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='Action')
async def show_invoices(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.from_user.id,
                           **ACTION.generate_invoices(), payload='12345')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='MMO')
async def show_invoices(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.from_user.id,
                           **MMO.generate_invoices(), payload='12345')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='RPG')
async def show_invoices(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.from_user.id,
                           **RGP.generate_invoices(), payload='12345')


@dp.shipping_query_handler()
async def choose_shipping(query: types.ShippingQuery):
    if query.shipping_address.country_code == 'RU':
        await bot.answer_shipping_query(shipping_query_id=query.id,
                                        shipping_options=[
                                            POST_REGULAR_SHIPPING,
                                            POST_FAST_SHIPPING,
                                            PICKUP_SHIPPING
                                        ],
                                        ok=True)
    elif query.shipping_address.country_code:
        await bot.answer_shipping_query(shipping_query_id=query.id,
                                        ok=False,
                                        error_message='Мы патриоты и работаем только по России\nВ выбранную вами страну товар не доставляем')


@dp.pre_checkout_query_handler()
async def process_pre_checkout_query(query: types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query_id=query.id, ok=True)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=query.from_user.id, text='Спасибо за покупку')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: саму оплату не проверял, но окно ввода реквизитов выводится, так что дума дальше разберетесь )) И не забудьте указать свои токены бота и `provider_token`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!

Comment: @Николай не за что ))